# SOAP request stopped to provide PidLidGlobalObjectId and PidLidCleanGlobalObjectId?

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I developed an Outlook addin which relies on `GlobalObjectId` to uniquely identify an event in the calendar. But suddenly the SOAP request I was using to the Exchange server stopped providing the GlobalObjectId and CleanGlobalObjectId.

I was using this request and it worked fine

```js
function generateCalendarUidSoapRequest (itemId) {
  const request = '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">' +
    '  <soap:Header><t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" /></soap:Header>' +
    '  <soap:Body>' +
    '    <m:GetItem>' +
    '      <m:ItemShape>' +
    '        <t:BaseShape>AllProperties</t:BaseShape>' +
    '      </m:ItemShape >' +
    '      <t:AdditionalProperties>' +
    '        <t:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:UID"/>' +
    '        <t:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="Meeting" PropertyId="3" PropertyType="Binary" />' +
    '        <t:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="Meeting" PropertyId="35" PropertyType="Binary" />' +
    '      </t:AdditionalProperties>' +
    '      <m:ItemIds>' +
    '        <t:ItemId Id="' + itemId + '" />' +
    '      </m:ItemIds>' +
    '    </m:GetItem>' +
    '  </soap:Body>' +
    '</soap:Envelope>'

  return request
}
```

The response gives no error but now it does not include any `<t:GlobalObjectId>` nor anything similar. Perhaps an update in the Exchange server? What can I do to fetch the GlobalObjectId or the CleanGlobalObjectId?

Comment: This appears to be purely an EWS/Exchange Server issue. Nothing unique to add-ins here unless making the same SOAP request outside of an add-in environment provides the desired information whereas that information is missing in the add-in environment.

The `makeEwsRequest` async API for Outlook add-ins simply routes SOAP requests through Outlook, so I don't think this post is unique to Outlook add-ins. I'm dropping the Outlook add-ins tags. Please re-add them if this issue is unique to the add-ins environment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have no problem when requesting these two properties using the following:

```xml
    <t:AdditionalProperties>
      <t:ExtendedFieldURI PropertyType="Binary" PropertyId="3"  PropertySetId="6ed8da90-450b-101b-98da-00aa003f1305"/>
      <t:ExtendedFieldURI PropertyType="Binary" PropertyId="35" PropertySetId="6ed8da90-450b-101b-98da-00aa003f1305"/>
    </t:AdditionalProperties>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but unfortunately I just tested with your exemple and it doesn't work. GlobalObjectId is not being shown in the response. I get a lot of fields, but no GlobalObjectId

Comment: Are the ids actually present? Can you see them in OutlookSpy if you click the IMessage button?

Comment: no, the XML response does not even include those ids

Comment: Are they visible in the IMessage window? Can you specify them in the EWS request (EWS | GetItem | Get Item Call Parameters | Additional Properties | check ExtendedFieldURI | Add From Current MAPI Object)